# How to search substring in a mysql field and replace with something else

Tags: mysql, sql-update

For instance,

I wanna search by substring "S2000" and replace with "Honda" so all the following will match and replace the all the fields with "Honda"

```
Suspension;Coilovers;Honda;S2000
Exterior;Body Kits;Honda;S2000
Exterior;Other;Honda;S2000
Exterior;Bumpers / Lips;Honda;S2000
Exterior;Fenders;Honda;S2000
Engine;Exhaust;Honda;S2000
```

Im running this query in attempt to replace "Suspension;Coilovers;Honda;S2000" with "Coilovers" and it didn't work as I intended to.

```
update table set category = replace(category, 'Coilovers', 'Coilovers') WHERE category like '%Coilovers%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated post you would do this:

```
update table set category = 'Coilovers' WHERE category like '%Coilovers%'
```

Here is the documentation on update queries:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Basically, the part `set category='Coilovers` will change the category column value to `Coilovers`.

Comment: Thats what I tried but didn't work. See updated post.

Comment: you nailed it. Thanks!